# How to delete previous incarnation in MySQL (/w Group Replication)

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-cluster

There exist almost no mentions whatsoever of MySQL "incarnations", so I'm opening this topic to make a precedent, even if I solve it myself. Feel free to help of course :)

```
2018-08-10T16:21:34.795206Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Old incarnation found while trying to add node fuelstat-db-1.novarumcloud.com:33061 15339180934204040.'
```

The Group Replication member node fails to join the GR cluster with the above error, after I have rebuilt the same server. I've checked the internal MySQL tables and I still can't locate what makes it unhappy with that "incarnation". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by bringing down the entire cluster, as mentioned in a similar issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/q1FEA4Q0z3Q). After the restart, bringing the GR cluster back up from scratch had no mentions of incarnations.